# How can I receive SOL from an account into a program?

Tags: solana-program, rust

I'm an EVM smart contract developer and new to solana. I'm trying to implement a program in solana where users can deposit/withdraw SOL to participate in a bet. How can I implement a `payable` like functionality where users can send SOL while calling an instruction.

This is the code I currently have

```
fn transfer_sol<'a>(
    signer: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    recepient: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    amount: u64,
) -> ProgramResult {
    // Create the system transfer instruction
    let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(signer.key, recepient.key, amount);

    msg!("Transferring from {} to {}", signer.key, recepient.key);

    // Send the transfer instruction
    solana_program::program::invoke(
        &transfer_instruction,
        &[signer.clone(), recepient.clone(), system_program],
    )?;

    msg!("Transferred {} SOL", amount);

    Ok(())
}
```

when I run this code, I keep getting this error

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
```

Do I need to include some account in the account_info array for this to work

Comment: Make sure to check that the recipient is what you are expecting and the users are not just passing in their own address. Just a tip, it's a common pitfall.

Answer (score 5):

You’ll have to make sure that both the sending and receiving account are marked as `mut` on the client side.

If you’re using anchor, you can do this by annotating the account field with the `#[account(mut)]` attribute. This reflects in the IDL and generated client scaffold, and marks that account as mutable.

Otherwise, if you’re building your project without anchor, make sure that when constructing your client-side instruction, the `AccountMeta` objects for those accounts have their `isMutable` fields set to true.